# CopyToOutputDirectory copies dll files to bin instead of root

Tags: .net, msbuild

I'm setting up deployment for a .net core project. During the publish step some files need to be copied to the output folder and I'm using CopyToOutputDirectory to do this.

```
<None Update="SomeFolder\*.*">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</None>
```

Everything except the dll file in the folder gets copied to the right place whereas the dll goes into bin + whatever default path. Is there any way to change this behaviour?

```
Example:
Original structure
root
-SomeFolder
--file1.exe
--file2.dll

Output structure
root
-SomeFolder
--file1.exe
-bin
--Somefolder
---file2.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

`CopyToOutputDirectory` is metadata that is used by the 'build', not the 'publish'.

For a source file listed in the project file, the `CopyToOutputDirectory` metadata indicates that the file should be copied to the target output directory (e.g. "bin\Debug\net6.0"). For a class library project, the target output of the project is the DLL and the DLL is not a source file.

You can tailor publishing with a publish profile - see "[dotnet publish command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish)" and "[Visual Studio publish profiles (.pubxml) for ASP.NET Core app deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/visual-studio-publish-profiles?view=aspnetcore-7.0)" for the details.